# Finding time differences by id R

Tags: r

I have the following data(df)

```
Id        Timestamp                 Event
 1    2015-11-06 06:11:43           mail subscribed
 1    2015-11-06 06:15:43           Invoice created
 1    2015-11-06 09:15:43           phone call
 2    2015-11-07 08:15:43           New subscription
 2    2015-11-07 08:20:43           Added to customer list.
```

I am looking for the following,(Time difference for every id)

For example, Id=1 has three different events with different timings, I want to calculate the differences between the individual times between events based on Id.

```
Id        Timestamp                 Event                   Time Difference(Mins)
 1    2015-11-06 06:11:43           mail subscribed           0.0
 1    2015-11-06 06:15:43           Invoice created           5.0         
 1    2015-11-06 09:15:43           phone call                180.0
 2    2015-11-07 08:15:43           New subscription          0.0
 2    2015-11-07 08:20:43           Added to customer list    5.0
```

I tried the following code,

```
 diff = function(x) as.numeric(x - lag(x) )
 or diff = function (x) as.numeric(0L,diff(x))
 setDT(df)[, diff2 := diff(timestamp), by = Id]
```

But this code outputs irregular results. Any help?

Comment: Not clear. What do you want to obtain?

Comment: Maybe you could try `difftime`?

Comment: @nicola I updated my question

Comment: @Jaap I checked "difftime", it doesn't work by id, but it works individually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `ave`.  No packages are used.

```
transform(df, Diff = ave(as.numeric(Timestamp), Id, FUN = function(x) c(0, diff(x))/60))
```

giving:

```
  Id           Timestamp                            Event Diff
1  1 2015-11-06 06:11:43                  mail subscribed    0
2  1 2015-11-06 06:15:43                  Invoice created    4
3  1 2015-11-06 09:15:43                       phone call  180
4  2 2015-11-07 08:15:43                 New subscription    0
5  2 2015-11-07 08:20:43           Added to customer list    5
```

**Note:**  This was used for the input data.frame, `DF`

```
Lines <- "Id,        Timestamp,                 Event
 1,    2015-11-06 06:11:43,           mail subscribed
 1,    2015-11-06 06:15:43,          Invoice created
 1,    2015-11-06 09:15:43,          phone call
 2,    2015-11-07 08:15:43,          New subscription
 2,    2015-11-07 08:20:43,          Added to customer list"

df <- read.csv(text = Lines)
df$Timestamp <- as.POSIXct(df$Timestamp)
```

**UPDATED** as per comment.

Comment: Looking at the desired result, it seems that he wants `c(0,diff(x))` rather than `x-x[1]`, but I may be wrong. +1, I was about to propose the same `ave`-based solution.

Comment: G. Grothendieck GroThanks for the solution and also @nicola, that helped :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with the package `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Diff := difftime(Timestamp, Timestamp[1], units="mins"), by=Id]

df
#   Id           Timestamp                   Event     Diff
#1:  1 2015-11-06 06:11:43         mail subscribed   0 mins
#2:  1 2015-11-06 06:15:43         Invoice created   4 mins
#3:  1 2015-11-06 09:15:43              phone call 184 mins
#4:  2 2015-11-07 08:15:43        New subscription   0 mins
#5:  2 2015-11-07 08:20:43 Added to customer list.   5 mins
```

**Edit**

As per @Jaap comment, if what you need is the consecutive differences, you can do:

```
df[, Diff2 := difftime(Timestamp, shift(Timestamp, 1L), units = "mins"), by = Id
   ][is.na(Diff2), Diff2:=0]

df
#   Id           Timestamp                   Event     Diff    Diff2
#1:  1 2015-11-06 06:11:43         mail subscribed   0 mins   0 mins
#2:  1 2015-11-06 06:15:43         Invoice created   4 mins   4 mins
#3:  1 2015-11-06 09:15:43              phone call 184 mins 180 mins
#4:  2 2015-11-07 08:15:43        New subscription   0 mins   0 mins
#5:  2 2015-11-07 08:20:43 Added to customer list.   5 mins   5 mins
```

Comment: Or: `setDT(mydf)[, dff := difftime(Timestamp, shift(Timestamp,1L), units = "mins"), by = Id]`

Comment: @Jaap, indeed, if the desired result is more `c(0, diff(x))`, thanks :-)